# Click on an object to open an image using a QGIS action

Tags: qgis, actions

I'm working on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46684/25139) from @Nathan W to find how to deal with missing files, as they return a error message if QGIS doesn't find any.

The initial workflow is to be able to click on an object (here a point which is a borehole) and open the related crosscut, that I have renamed from the borehole name. If the crosscut doesn't exist, I'd like to display a message saying this crosscut is not referenced. All the images are in jpg format and are in a folder named "Fichiers_Coupes_SCAN" ad my image name is in the attribute table in a column named "ID_SONDAGE".

My code is the following :

```
from os import startfile
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join, isfile
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
proj = QgsProject.instance()
urfile = str(proj.fileName())
path = join(abspath(dirname(urfile)),"Fichiers_Coupes_SCAN", "[% "ID_SONDAGE" %]"".jpg")
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(path) :
    startfile(path)
else:
    QMessageBox.information(None, "Error : ","Can't find the crosscut")
```

I'd like the error message to display the name of the borehole, but I must do something wrong and I get error messages when inserting the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I found out ! It was just a syntax error when inserting the expression that got back the attribute value from the expression builder tool. One needs to add "" around the expression.

```
from os import startfile
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join, isfile
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
proj = QgsProject.instance()
urfile = str(proj.fileName())
path = join(abspath(dirname(urfile)),"Fichiers_Coupes_SCAN", "[% "ID_SONDAGE" %]"".jpg")
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(path) :
    startfile(path)
else:
    QMessageBox.information(None, "Erreur : ","[%'The crosscut from the borehole  '  ||  "ID_SONDAGE"  || ' can't be found'%]")
```